# Open Password Protected Excel Workbook C#

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, password-protection

I am trying to open a password protected Excel workbook. I have tried many different ways of unprotecting it programatically or inputting the password, yet every time my program runs, I m prompted to input the password. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class AttenFile
    {
        private Excel.Application excel;
        private Excel.Workbook wb;
        private Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        private Excel.Range range;
        private const  int startRow = 3;
        private int row;
        private static Object MissingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        public AttenFile(String attenFileDir)
        {
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(attenFileDir, MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue, "nso" );
            wb.Unprotect("nso");
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) wb.Sheets[1];
            worksheet.Unprotect("nso");
            range = worksheet.UsedRange;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you accessing the Workbook.Password property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.password(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yep. Just tried wb.Password = "nso"; Still prompting for password.

Comment: I noticed there are also options to get password encryption type and password encryption provider. I would investigate this as it may be relying on an encrypted password to be sent. Hope this helps somewhat!